# Suddenly getting 1 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I suddenly got +1 reputation. I did however downvote an answer and I was thinking, Is his answer deleted? And am I getting that 1 reputation back?

This happend a couple of times. I think it's because of a deleted answer I've downvoted, but it could be something else.

Comment: What's your actual question here? Can you clear what you want to know in your question please?

Comment: I want to know if I'm right about what I told in the question.

Comment: What reason are you seeing next to +1 in your reputation tab?

Comment: Provide a link to the answer you downvoted?

Comment: At the bottom of your reputation history, did you enable "show removed posts"?

Comment: @hims056 there isn't a +1 in my reputation tab. that's why I asked. I thought it was strange.

Comment: Thanks @Bart that's it :) Thanks.